# create a Slider using SPservice

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, spservices

Here is a Javascript for sliding images (with some contents)  http://pgwjs.com/pgwslider/ Which I really like. I would like to use exactly this in a SharePoint List.

How can I connect this slider to a Sharepoint list using SPservice?

Answer (score 1):

list means??here u want create one web part in which you want to fetch images from list, and display them in the same slider,right??if it is.then  it depends which web part you are creating,its custom web part or Out of the box web part and if it is custom web part then which solution you are using??
 if it is OOTB then its pretty much simple ,where u will simply add CQWP and select the list,and after that add one Script Editr and apply same html and css structure and if it is custom web part then apply code as following in .cs file of web part

```
 using (SPSite objSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
            {
                using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                                SPList objList;
                                SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();                  
                                objQuery.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNotNull></Where>";                   
                                objQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Pic_Description' /><FieldRef Name='Picture' />";                           
                                objList = objWeb.Lists[ListTitle];    
                                SPListItemCollection items = objList.GetItems(objQuery);

                               //ur HTML structure if ur using generic html 

                  }
             }
```

and link java script and css using script editor
hope this will help full to you